# SharePoint REST API for Fetching custom Metadata Columns

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I am Developing a plugin that exports Documents to SharePoint Repository after processing them. Along with the document, I need to send values for Custom Metadata columns defined in SharePoint.

I have figured out how to send across Files and Metadata to a specified location.

Problem: Initially, I do not know what custom metadata columns are available in the given folder. 
Could someone shed light on any REST webservice that can fetch the available Metadata Columns for a given location in the repository.

Note: I am using pure Java for REST Requests using Apache HTTP Client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST url for retrieving the custom fields in a list is:

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Custom List')/fields
```

I don't know much about parsing JSON in java but this will give you a list of all the columns and extensive details about them.  I displayed some of the data returned below.

```
DefaultValue : null
Description : ""
EnforceUniqueValues : false
Id : "fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd123"
Indexed : false
InternalName : "Title"
ReadOnlyField : false
Required : false
StaticName : "Title"
Title : "Title"
FieldTypeKind : 2
TypeAsString : "Text"
TypeDisplayName : "Single line of text"
```

If you need to get the available columns of a specific folder, and not a library:

```
_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/Shared%20Documents/Folder')/ListItemAllFields
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 has a REST API endpoint that could retrieve and filter Metadata columns if you obtain the information through a `POST` request using `CAML`. If your requests were made from SharePoint itself, you would use the masterpage's `RequestDigest`, but since you are doing it remotely, you would have to get this parameter by querying `/_api/contextinfo` and obtaining the `FormDigestValue`. Here is an article on it:

http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2013/09/23/how-to-filter-on-a-managed-metadata-column-via-rest-in-sharepoint-2013/

Also, you must enable `CORS` on your SharePoint data repository.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```